# How to Separate routes with and without query param?

Tags: node.js, express

Simple question, how can i set the routes so that it goes to the correct route,

```
app.get("/:post",(req,res) => {})
```

AND

```
app.get("/post",(req,res) => {})
```

This happens when i typed "/post", the server is confused if it should go to "/post" route or "/:post". This applies to routes that is similiar "/publish" "/logout" "/login".

Please share the knowledge on how to fix this, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the routes also important in this case. It cabn be solved by defining the route `app.get("/post",(req,res) => {})` prior to `app.get("/:post",(req,res) => {})`.
In this case if you called something like `http://localhost:3000/..../post` sure it will go to the route `/post` and rest of the calls are to the next route.

`..................
app.get("/post",(req,res) => {})
app.get("/:post",(req,res) => {})
...........................`

If we do like above then the server won't get confused I think.

Comment: This is what i've been looking for, thank you ver much :D

Answer (score 1):

If you are using below routes then you need to pass some `parameters` into your `URL`

```
app.get("/:post",(req,res) => {})
```

But if you are looking for routes that don't return anything from the `URL` then you used below routes

```
app.get("/post",(req,res) => {})
```

So, if you're using 1 route then you need to pass some `parameters` in your `URL`

Answer (score 0):

That's because `/:post` matches the resources that you mention (`/post`, `/publish`, `/logout` etc). To solve this use a noun prior the wildcard, such as `/post/:post`. In that way, you avoid the ambiguity.

Comment: That said, you'll have the following routes:
```
/post
/publish
/logout
/login
/post/:post
```

Comment: is there any way other than this? since both method is in the same router file (portofolio.js).

this link:[
/post =>  localhost:3000/portofolio/post
/:post => localhost:3000/portfolio/anything
]

will become
/:post => localhost:3000/portoflio/post/anything

i'd like to avoid this if possible

Comment: @AnotherWeeb the current approach that you're attempting to do will lead to confuse the router. Could you give an example of the /anything route that you're attempting to resolve? and also, could you try to put the /:post after all the paths definitions?